# Get line+column in HTML string of tag matching a selector

Tags: javascript, html, parsing

Given HTML source code as a string, is it possible to find the start and end column + line number that a tag appears on given a CSS selector for that tag? For example, given this string:

```
<h1>test</h1><h1 class="cls">
<p>1234</p>456</h1><p>789
```

I want to know the start and end positions of the tag that matches the selector "h1.cls".

I know I can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser to parse the string into HTML and fetch tags with selectors but I can't see any way to get the line numbers the tags would be on e.g.:

```
const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(input, "text/html");
```

Comment: You could try converting your selector into a regular expression, but mixing HTML 
 and regexes [has some  known issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2059482). Any chance you could explain why you're trying to do this? It seems rather odd to be trying to map from the semi-abstract DOM tree *back* to the literal text of the document.

Comment: @solarshado I'm trying to highlight errors in the HTML like a linter, problems unsupported tags and bad IDs. I use selectors to find elements with problems with jquery style code then want to display the errors found to the user. I'd rather not use regexes but they're not reliable.

Comment: In that case, you should probably avoid anything like DOMParser; I'm sure it's as lenient and forgiving as possible, like browsers are. You're going to need something that'll parse the text at a much lower level, and likely won't have support for anything as advanced as CSS selectors. A bit of googling turned up [this](https://github.com/chinchiheather/html-linter) existing linter which might make a decent starting point.